# Unexpected token ILLEGAL when load fonts with .woff extention

Tags: javascript, security, web, fonts, mime-types

I've tried to setup MIME types in many different way like:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/opentype" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

But in any case I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL tinymce.woff:1` Tested in last version of firefox and chrome

Comment: How did you get the woff file? This looks like a problem within the file.

Comment: @JanDvorak It was used before i come to team. I am involved into  bug fixing

Comment: How are you trying to load those files? The error message sounds like the browser is trying to parse them as Javascript, which isn't right.

Comment: @duskwuff I load it like  `<script src="/WebMvcLOP/Scripts/Libs/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.woff"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot load fonts using a `<script>` tag. That's only used for Javascript files.

Fonts must be loaded using a `@font-face` CSS rule, e.g:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans';
    src: url('/s/gillsans.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

For more information, see [MDN's article on `@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).